# How do I show a PDF in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, rubygems

I'm using [pdfjs_viewer-rails](https://github.com/senny/pdfjs_viewer-rails) gem and when I try to load a custom PDF in this way

```
<%= pdfjs_viewer pdf_url: "http://biblioteca2.ucab.edu.ve/anexos/biblioteca/marc/texto/AAM8264.pdf", style: :full %>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
PDF.js v1.10.100 (build: ea29ec83)
Message: file origin does not match viewer's
```

I searched in internet and as I understand I have to setup CORS but I don't understand how.

If there's any other way to show PDF without print and download button which isn't the google toobar method I apreciate it. (I know it's impossible to prevent a PDF being downloaded, this is just a work for an assignature for my college).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could proxy the PDF file through your own server. This should resolve any issues you have with CORS or other cross-domain problems.

#### Step 1 - Add new route for proxy controller

```
get "proxy/:url" => "proxy#index", :constraints => { :url => /.*/ }
```

#### Step 2 - Create the proxy controller

```
require 'open-uri'

class ProxyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    url = params[:url]
    url.gsub!(/(https?:\/)/, '\1/')  

    # Note there is no error handling here. 
    # This is only proof of concept.
    data = open(url)

    send_data data.read,
      :type        => data.content_type,
      :disposition => 'inline'
  end
end
```

#### Step 3 - Modify view to use proxy

```
<%= pdfjs_viewer 
    pdf_url: "/proxy/http://remote-server.com/remotefile.pdf", 
    style: :full %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you get `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: dh key too small` when downloading from https you should use Net::HTTP instead setting `ciphers` options:

```
class ProxyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    url = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(params[:url])
    uri = URI.parse(url)

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.ciphers = "DEFAULT:!DH"
    response = http.get(uri.request_uri)

    send_data(response.body, type: response.content_type, disposition: :inline)
  end
end
```